# Video problem with Totem in 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: totem

I recently upgrated to 22.04.1LTS but find now I cannot open .mp4 videos. The error message says "Totem could not start up. Some necessary plug-ins are missing. Make sure that the program is correctly installed". How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the gstreamer codecs from the add-ons section of software app. And, or `rm -r ~/.cache/totem`. You can again try `rm -r ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/`